# What does 行けそうなら mean?

Tags: grammar

In the song Diver by Nico Touches the Walls there is this line, そこまで行けそうなら. I have been scratching my head on this for years actually, just remembered it recently. I don't think I've seen anywhere else そう and なら used together. Should I just take it at face value, "if it seems like I can go there"? Which sounds bizzare.

And later on there is どこまで行けそうかな which makes a little more sense to me, "I wonder how far can I go", but just want to check I'm understanding this right. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the song and so don't know the context, but what's bizarre about "if it seems like I can go there" (or perhaps "if it seems like I can go that far")? It seems fine to me, in both Japanese and English, and there's certainly nothing unusual about the combination of 連用形 ＋ そう ＋ なら.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal translation is indeed "if it seems like I can go there". そうなら is a very common combination:

- 長くなりそうなら言ってください。
  If you think it's going to take time, tell me.
- できそうならやってください。
  If it looks possible to you, please do it.

So [the context](http://j-lyric.net/artist/a04dac3/l023e1d.html) is that he is seeing a subtle light (or "hope"), but it's very far, and he is still wondering which direction to go at this point. Read between the lines like "If I can go there, I should, but I'm not sure if I can".